# Creating a directory within directories using the python scripting language

Tags: python, path, directory

Please find my python script below:

```
import os;
import sys;

dir_dst = sys.argv[1]

for x in range(150) :
    dirname = str(x)
    dst_dir = os.path.join(dir_dst, dirname)
    dirname = "annotation"
    dst = os.path.join(dst_dir, dirname)
    print dst
    if not os.path.exists(dst_dir):
        os.mkdir(dst)
```

The aim is to create a directory called "annotation" within each of the numbered directories ranging as in the code above. This code doesn't do it and on printing the value of "dst", here's an example of what it shows:

```
NLP/test data/reconcile/0\annotation
NLP/test data/reconcile/1\annotation
```

How can this be resolved?

Comment: no need to use `;` after the `import` statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the second to last line to

```
if not os.path.exists(dst):
```

Right now you're checking if the original directory exists.